# configure IPA Client (FreeIPA) on a Linux machine

Tags: linux, freeipa

I am getting this error while I am going to configure IPA Cleint (FreeIPA) on a Linux machine.

```
Kerberos authentication failed
kinit: Clock skew too great while getting initial credentials

Please make sure the following ports are opened in the firewall settings:
     TCP: 80, 88, 389
     UDP: 88 (at least one of TCP/UDP ports 88 has to be open)
Also note that following ports are necessary for ipa-client working properly after enrollment:
     TCP: 464
     UDP: 464, 123 (if NTP enabled)
Installation failed. Rolling back changes.
IPA client is not configured on this system.
```

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites http://unix.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: AND use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The time is not sync between IPA client and IPA server.
Go to your client and activate NTP yum package to sync the clock:

```
yum install ntp
service ntpd restart
date
```

In case, it won't get updated, follow these steps to update the local time:

```
rm -f /etc/localtime
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Chicago /etc/localtime
```

(E.g. you are living in the central time zone)

Answer (score 0):

This indeed means that the time offset between the ipa server and the client is to important.

You will need to sync the time between both machines with ntpdate.

On client:

`yum install ntpdate -y && ntpdate ipa_server`

If needed, there is also an argument to avoid ntp setup:

`--force-ntpd`